# Schur complement condition number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number, schur-complement

How can I most simply show, without referring to advanced theorems, that the Schur complement is better-conditioned than the original SPD matrix itself?

Comment: Not sure which theorems are qualified as advanced, but you may see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2749464 for a proof.

Comment: I would like to avoid using the Courant-Fischer principle.

Comment: It's always there in one way or [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994633/spektre-schur-complement).