# Problem relate to condition number of Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{21}^T\\
A_{21} & A_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$
, which is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and $A_{11} \in \mathbb{R}^{pxp}$ which is invertible.

(a) Prove the Schur complement

$S=A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{21}^T$

satisfies $\kappa_2(S) \leq \kappa_{2}(A)$

(b) Prove that $\lVert A_{21}A_{11}^{-1} \rVert_2 \leq \kappa_2(A)^{1/2}$

where $\kappa_2$ is the condition number with matrix 2 norm

For problem (a) I have already done it.

I can't figure out how to solve problem (b) though.

I know that in this case $\kappa_2(A)^{1/2}=\frac{\lambda_{max}(A)}{\lambda_{min}(A)}$, and I tried everything in my head but still couldn't get it. Am I missing something?

Comment: It might be helpful to rewrite the inequality as 
$$
\|A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}\|_2^2 \leq \kappa_2(A) \implies\\
\lambda_{\max}(A_{21}A_{11}^{-2}A_{21}^T) \leq \frac{\lambda_{\max}(A)}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}
$$

Comment: Also, if you could briefly explain how you did part a, that might be helpful

Comment: I am using the [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994633/spektre-schur-complement/1994997#1994997/)

Comment: I can understand the inequality you gave me, but do I need another decomposition for A or something to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Another potentially helpful observation, however, is that the condition that $A$ is positive definite is necessary for this part (but wasn't necessary for part a). Otherwise, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{t & 1\\ 1 & t}
$$
serves as a counterexample. As $t \to \infty$, $\kappa(A) \to 1$ but $\|A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}\|_2 = t \to \infty$.

Comment: Is there a chance that you copied the question incorrectly?

Comment: No, I've checked it, nothing wrong.